# JWT token can not fetching when the site has been deployed. In localhost it's works fine

Tags: express, jwt, mern

In localhost client side fetching JWT token properly. But when the site I uploaded on render the client side can't fetching the token, though the token has been generated.

Here's my backend code `

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const userDoc = await User.findOne({ username });
    const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
    if (passOk) {
      jwt.sign(
        { username, id: userDoc._id },
        secret,
        { expiresIn: "1d" },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.cookie("token", token).json({ id: userDoc._id, username });
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "failed",
      message: err,
    });
  }
});

app.get("/profile", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(info);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: err,
    });
  }
});
```

Here's my client side code where I want to fetch the data ..

```
const { setUserInfo, userInfo } = useContext(UserContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchHandler = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`${backendURL}/profile`, {
        credentials: "include",
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setUserInfo(data);
    };
    fetchHandler();
  }, [setUserInfo]);
# When I added the right credentials the token has been generated but can't able to fetch token. Though the same code works fine in localhost. Unfortunately not working when it has been deployed.
Here some image I added from the network tab ..
[1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8UyF.png)
[2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMrBn.png)
[3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt1yP.png)
[4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5nIE.png)

I expecting it should work fine when I try to login. I tried to login so many time but showing the above error.
```